# Use go.rice with http.ServeFile()

Tags: go

Maybe I'm looking at the wrong places, but I cannot find an example of using go.rice with `http.ServeFile()`. Basically what I want is serve a boxed file with `http.ServeFile()`. What I have now is the following. As you can see I'm looking for a way to get the string location of a boxed file, since http.ServeFile requires that. I don't know how to get it. Any suggestions?

```
var StaticBox *rice.Box

func NewStaticBox() {
    StaticBox = rice.MustFindBox("../../static")
}

func Static(req *http.Request, resp *http.Response) {
    stringToBoxedFile := WHAT-TO-DO-HERE
    http.ServeFile(req, resp, stringToBoxedFile)
}
```

I can use the rice.box in various ways. I can get a file contents as a string with `StaticBox.String()`, etc. But now I want a string as a "location" to a boxed file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [http.ServeContent](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent) instead.
Get a [HTTPBox](https://godoc.org/github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice#Box.HTTPBox) and use  [HTTPBox.Open](https://godoc.org/github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice#HTTPBox.Open) to get a http.File, which implements io.ReadSeeker, so it can be used with ServeContent.

Alternatively, you could use [HTTPBox](https://godoc.org/github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice#HTTPBox) with http.FileServer, as suggested in the documentation of go.rice (http.FileServer will get the path of the request, and use that as a filename to find the file in the box.)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a very simple and short solution to achieve what you want:

```
func main() {
 box := rice.MustFindBox("../../static")
 http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(box.HTTPBox()))
 http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```